# In Fusiontime charts, can we change the formatting of yaxis values?

Tags: fusioncharts

I am using the fusioncharts for showing the metrics of crypto, so if the value in billions it is showing as giga, can i change the format to billions ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djoVC.png)

I changed the format like `decimals: 2` and expected to show the billion data with B

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can return a method under the formatted properties to format the y-axis numbers, here is a snippet below -

```
format: {
    formatter: obj => {
      if (obj.type === "axis") {
        return `${obj.value / 1000000000}B`
      }
      return obj.value.toString().replace(".", ",");
}
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/r0fbpsqj/

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding you can refer to the below docs to format Y-Axis value -

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/fusiontime-component/y-axis-in-fusiontime

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/fusiontime-component/y-axis-in-fusiontime#automatic-number-formatting